# Ellipse circumference calculation method?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Actually I know how to calculate the circumference of an ellipse using two methods and each one of them giving me different result.

The first method is using the formula: $E_c=2\pi\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$

The second method is determining the arc length of the first quart in the ellipse using **elliptic integral** multiplied by 4 (Look at picture below):

[image: Second method]

I want to know wath is the best method to get the exact circumference of an ellipse ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is an approximation, but it fails badly for $a \ll b $. Overall, I would recommend the exact formula of $4a E(e) $, which can be calculated quickly using the [Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGM_method).

Comment: Thanks but I just didn't understand the AGM method

Comment: @MohammadFakhrey, here's [a paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/201208/rtx120801094p.pdf) regarding how to compute $E(e)$ with this method. (If you're still confused, there's also an infinite sum you can calculate $E(e)$ with, but I don't exactly remember how it goes.)

Comment: Use the python code given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference to compute the circumference using AGM.

Answer (score 2):

The formula $E_c=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$ is not a bad approximation when $a$ is not far from $b$, but it is not a correct expression for the perimeter.

For example, when $a=1000$ and $b=1$, the true perimeter is not far from $4000$, and the formula predicts about $4440$.